# django rest framework reverse foreign field doesn't updated, return empty list

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have following model structure,

```
class Bill(models.Model):
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='bill_created_by')

    total_bill_amount = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

class Route(models.Model):
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False,blank=True, null=True)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False,blank=True, null=True)
    start_lat = models.FloatField(default=0.0,blank=True, null=True)
    start_lon = models.FloatField(default=0.0,blank=True, null=True)
    end_lat = models.FloatField(default=0.0,blank=True, null=True)
    end_lon = models.FloatField(default=0.0,blank=True, null=True)
    distance = models.FloatField(default=0.0,blank=True, null=True)
    transport = models.CharField(max_length=300,blank=True, null=True, choices=ROUTE_MODE, default=ROUTE_MODE[0])
    fare = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    purpose = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    bill = models.ForeignKey(Bill, related_name="routes",on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,blank=True, null=True, related_name='routes', max_length=255)
```

and the serializers,

```
class BillSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    routes = RouteSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Bill
        fields = ('id','created_on','created_by','total_bill_amount','routes') 

lass RouteSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    all_directions = AllDirectionSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    user = ReadOnlyField(source='user.email')
    bill = ReadOnlyField(source='bill.id')
    class Meta:
        model = Route
        fields = ('id','start_time','end_time','start_lat','start_lon','fare',
        'end_lat','end_lon','distance','transport','all_directions','user', 'bill')
```

and `Bill` api using viewset,

```
class BillViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Bill.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BillSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)
```

now if i want to **update** `Bill` api with list of `Routes` according to the serializer structure, like this

```
**calling put method on Bill api where Bill id is 29**

   {
   "id": 29,
   "created_on": "2017-10-15T10:05:19.786057Z",
   "created_by": 4,
   "total_bill_amount": 301,
   "routes": [
    {
        "id": 31,
        "start_time": null,
        "end_time": null,
        "start_lat": 23.77201,
        "start_lon": 90.3602333333333,
        "fare": 0,
        "end_lat": 0.0,
        "end_lon": 0.0,
        "distance": 0.0,
        "transport": "BUS",
        "all_directions": [],
        "user": "tanvir@gmal.com",
        "bill": 29
       },
       {
        "id": 32,
        "start_time": null,
        "end_time": null,
        "start_lat": 23.7715316666667,
        "start_lon": 90.3604483333333,
        "fare": 0,
        "end_lat": 0.0,
        "end_lon": 0.0,
        "distance": 0.0,
        "transport": "BUS",
        "all_directions": [],
        "user": "tanvir@gmail.com",
        "bill": 29
       }    
       ]
       }
```

it only update `Bill` attribute, say i updated `total_bill_amount` form 301 to 700, its updated successfully but `routes` list become empty like this,

```
**Result after calling put method**

{
"id": 29,
"created_on": "2017-10-15T09:47:50.913255Z",
"created_by": 4,
"total_bill_amount": 700,
"routes": []
}
```

what's wrong i am doing here? why `routes` doesn't get updated?

Comment: You need to read the documentation about nested serializers.

Comment: can you be specific actually where is the problem with my code? @Linovia

Answer (score 1):

By default, DRF won't update `routes`. You should override `update` method of your serializer, like this:

```
class BillSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    routes = RouteSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Bill
        fields =('id','created_on','created_by','total_bill_amount','routes')

    def update(self, instance, validated_data)
        instance = super().update(instance, validated_data)

        routes = validated_data.get('routes')

        if routes:
            for route_info in routes:
                Route.objects.filter(id=route_info['id']).update(**route_info)

        return instance
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: unfortunately its not woking, in fact `validated_data` contains `{'created_by': <User: tanvir@gmail.com>, 'total_bill_amount': 704}` ,does not contain `routes`, thus its does not enter the next `if` block. @Jahongir Rahmonov

Comment: @Md.TanvirRaihan you need to remove `read_only=True` from `RouteSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)`

Comment: after remove `read_only=True` its raise following error   `The `.update()` method does not support writable nested fields by default.
Write an explicit `.update()` method for serializer `conveyance.serializers.BillSerializer`, or set `read_only=True` on nested serializer fields. `

Comment: @Md.TanvirRaihan make sure you wrote `update` correctly because you already have `.update()` method in your serializer

Comment: didn't get you this time, can you please update your answer.

Comment: @Md.TanvirRaihan there is nothing to update. Just write the word `update` correctly.

Comment: my current code   

    `def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance = super().update(instance, validated_data)

        routes = validated_data.get('routes')
        print("GGGGG", validated_data)

        if routes:
            for route_info in routes:
                Route.objects.filter(id=route_info['id']).update(**route_info)
        return instance `

Comment: @Md.TanvirRaihan and that `update` is inside `BillSerializer`, not `RouteSerializer`. Correct?

Comment: i have write the word `update` correctly.its not working.

Comment: correct , i have written this update method in `BillSerializer` not it `RouteSerializer`

Comment: everything is fine, removed `read_only=True`, no error regarding this, but `routes` become `None` if i print out `validated_data.get('routes')` ? is there any problem with my `RouteSerializer` ? i am using DRF 3.6.2